# Rails Admin / Actionmailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, rails-admin

I am building a simple app that just uses rails_admin to collect data.  I have different types of Users set up to view and edit different models.  I want to send a summary email of a record when it is created using rials_admin.  Since I don't have a dedicate controller for this model, where do I create this action?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a callback.  You need to manually select the user who created record or user [mongoid_userstamp](https://github.com/tbpro/mongoid_userstamp) / ActiveRecord equivalent.

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  belongs_to :user
  after_create do
    YourMailer.send_report(user)
  end
  ...
end
class YourMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def send_report
    mail(...).deliver_later
  end
end
```